# Unexpected eval result in CLISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval

I run following code of CLISP, but the result looks strange to me.

```
(setq a 'b)
(setq b 'c)
(setq c 'd)
(setq d 8)
(eval a)
(eval c)
(eval (eval a))
```

The output of last three line is:

C

8

D

How do I understand the output?

**How could last two line have different output?**

Please help explain this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate `(eval c)`

1. get value of variable `c` -> symbol `D`
2. call EVAL with symbol `D` -> number **8**

Evaluate `(eval (eval a))`

1. get value of variable `a` -> symbol `B`
2. call EVAL with symbol `B` -> symbol `C`
3. call EVAL with symbol `C` -> symbol **D**

**Some basic evaluation rules for Lisp**

- a symbol evaluates to its value
- a number evaluates to itself
- a list `(foo-function arg)` evaluates first the argument and then calls the function `foo-function` with that evaluated argument
- a list `(quote something)` returns `something` (whatever it is) as it is

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so can I understand it like this:
The result of an expression(like c) is considered as (quote c), however, when a symbol is explicit written, it will be considered as its value?

Comment: @DUjio: the result of the expression `c` is the value of `c`. The result of `(quote c)` is the symbol `c`. The result of b is   the symbol `c`. Note that in your results there are no quoted values - there are symbols and numbers in your results.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and clear explanation, it is my first time to use stack overflow, and I never expected that I would get reply such soon!

Comment: @Dujio: it's a typical Lisp beginner question and its important to understand these evaluation rules, because you need it when you program in Lisp. Thus is very useful to ask these questions, since especially this part is a real initial hurdle: evaluation, symbols, `eval` as a function, `quote` as an operator...